# in c, if i have char *const* pointer, how do i access each and every element?

Tags: c, pointers, strcmp, qsort

this is for the qsort comparison function,

```
int cmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
    char *const* pp = p;
    char *const* qq = q;
    ...
}
```

i want to compare the elements of the two strings. i tried (*pp)[i] since *pp is p, but it doesnt seem to work. also, what is the advantage of catching p and q this way instead of just creating two const char *?

last but no least, i have another comparison function that is supposed to skip leading white spaces

```
int wcmp(const void *p, const void *q) {

    const char *pp = p;
    const char *qq = q;
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    while(isspace(*(pp+i))) {
        i++;
    }

    while(isspace(*(qq)+j)) {
        j++;
    }

    return strcmp(pp+i, qq+j);
}
```

but when i test it with

```
    d afdsa
   hello
  heal
```

the output is

```
  heal
    d afdsa
   hello
```

what is going on with "d afdsa" in the middle?

Comment: Is the type of `pp` literally `char * const *`, or are those asterisks meant for emphasis?

Comment: `char *const*` is a different animal than a `const char*`.  The first is a pointer to a pointer, the second is a pointer to a `char`.  So the first order of business is for you to understand what you really have in those void pointers.

Comment: `*(qq)+j` --> `*(qq+j)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qsort` works for elements of *any* size. The only way it can work is by passing *pointers* to the first bytes of the elements, and these are of type `const void *`.

So if you have an array of `int`s, the comparison function gets 2 pointers to `void`, that actually points to 2 `int`s in the array, and you compare the pointed-to objects:

```
int cmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
    int *pp = p;
    int *qq = q;
    return *pp - *qq; // for example, ignoring all possible UB and such.
}
```

Likewise, if you have an *array of pointers to char*, i.e. `char *array[]`, then each element is a pointer to char, and the comparison function gets passed in 2 arguments: pointers to const void that point to these elements. When you cast them back you get:

```
char *const *pp = p;
```

I.e. a pointer to a constant pointer to char. The actual objects that you must compare are *pointed-to by these pointers*.

And this is why your `wcmp` doesn't work:

```
int wcmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
    const char *pp = p;
    const char *qq = q;
    ...
}
```

This would be appropriate if each element in the array to be sorted was a `char`. But the elements were *pointers* to char, so it means that the arguments to `wcmp` (each of which points to an element in the array) must be converted to *pointers to pointers to char*:

```
int wcmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
    char *const *ptmp = p;
    char *const *qtmp = q;
```

Then you must dereference them to get the actual pointer to char

```
    char *pp = *ptmp; // dereference them
    char *qq = *qtmp;
```

Or, you can shorten those 2 to:

```
    char *pp = *(char *const *)p;
    char *qq = *(char *const *)q;
```

As for the rest of the `wcmp`, that's not really C - a true C programmer loves changing pointers:

```
    while(isspace(*pp)) {
        pp ++;
    }

    while(isspace(*qq)) {
        qq ++;
    }

    return strcmp(pp, qq);
}
```

that is, for as long as `pp` points to a space character, increment `pp` so that it points to the next character; and do the same for `qq` too, and then compare the strings whose first characters are pointed to by `pp` and `qq`.